# Git uninstalled by itself. What can cause that?

Tags: windows-7, git, visual-studio

I was installing the C++ packages for VS 2015 while looking for unused game folders to pass the time. Suddenly out of nowhere Git uninstalls itself! (the horror...) 
Granted, I was actively deleting things, however they were 5kb empty folders, not the most important program on my machine.

I was not prompted by ANY dialog of "Are you sure?" or "Do you want to delete X?". Git uninstall window just popped out of nowhere and even task manager didn't manage to kill it.

My only guess is that maybe because one of the VS 2015 packages I chose to install (together with the C++ package) was Github integration to VS (to which I thought "hell why not") but it's hard for me to believe MS would just delete my Git without so much as a warning...

Edit: installer finished and this came up:

[image]

Comment: Did you recently install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound yes I did include the update. Is this the culprit?

Comment: You were wondering how it was uninstalled.  If there was an update to that particular feature of Visual Studio the previous version would have been uinstalled and the new version would have been offered. If you didn't configure which modules were installed, that might explain the reason, it was uninstalled and not replaced with the current version.

Comment: That could be an answer :)

Comment: It does not explain the reason your unable to install Git though.  This is the type of question that is easier to self-answer.

Comment: I am perfectly able to install Git, and did so just now. I was wondering why it uninstalled by itself, not why I can't uninstall it (which I can).

Comment: Your screenshot indicate it failed to installl Git.  In any event I can't say with a 100% certainty the reason it was uninstalled without installer logs which likely no longer exist on your system.